# How can I pass a variable in one function to another function?

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular JS, I am passing an object property, `child.parentlink.id` to a function that is logging it properly. I'd like to pass this property to another function. I am not passing `child.parentlink.id` in `ng-click="goback()"` because my `ng-repeat` stops before that.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="wizardApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    ...
    <div id="pagetwo">

      <div ng-repeat="child in childresults">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:351px;" ng-click="showpagetwo(child.Title, child.ID, child.ParentLink.ID)" ng-if="child.Location == null">{{child.Title}}
          <span class="tooltiptextsmall tooltip-rightsmall" ng-if="child.TooltipSize =='Small'">{{child.TooltipText}}</span>
          <span class="tooltiptextnormal tooltip-rightnormal" ng-if="child.TooltipSize =='Normal'">{{child.TooltipText}}</span>
          <span class="tooltiptextbig tooltip-rightbig" ng-if="child.TooltipSize =='Big'">{{child.TooltipText}}</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Go Back" style="width:168.5px; margin-right:5.25px;" ng-click="goback()">
        <span><i class="left"></i> Go back</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('wizardApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){
  $scope.showpagetwo = function(title, id, parentlink){
    console.log("Title: " + title, id, parentlink); // logs correctly here
    ...
  };

  $scope.goback = function(parentlink){
    console.log(parentlink); // not logging here
    ...
  };

});
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `ng-click="goback(child.ParentLink.ID)"`?

Comment: You do not pass the parameter in your `ng-click`.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey @PM 77-1 I cannot pass the parameter in `ng-click` as my `ng-repeat` is stopped before.

Comment: @cfoster5 "ng-repeat is stopped before." can you please clarify? are you having errors on console?

Comment: @cfoster5 you need to describe better what you want to pass and what it looks like. Consider alternatives: `childresults[0].ParentLink.ID`

Comment: @Luxor001 The back button does not have any object properties associated with it so there is nothing to pass. I also did not want a back button everytime an object is looped through. Therefore, `ng-repeat` is only used for the buttons that have object properties. I'm trying to pass the `parentlink.id` that is passed to the `showpagetwo()` function to `goback()`.

Comment: If the parent link is one of the properties of each child. And your button "go back" has nothing to do with any of the children, why does the goBack function expect a parent link in the first place? What should this button do?

Comment: @JBNizet This button fires a web request that gets items where ID == `parentlink`.

Comment: The parentLink of what? The first child? The last child? The 234th child? Something else?

Comment: @JBNizet The parentlink that is logged in `showpagetwo()`.

Comment: Why don't you answer my question? Each child in the list displayed by ng-repeat has a "show page two" link that does something with the parent link of **that child**. Your go back button is out of the ng-repeat. There is a single go back button. So, which of the children's parent link should it use?

Comment: @JBNizet `showpagetwo()` fires a web request where the column ParentLink == `id` which is an object property of that child. `goback()` fires another web request where the column ID == `parentlink` that is logged in `showpagetwo`. The parent link that `goback()` should be using is the one that was passed to `showpagetwo()`.

Comment: Ah, then store, in a field of your component, the parentLink passed to showpagetwo (i.e. `this.parentLinkToGoBackTo = parentlink;`)., and in the goBack function, use ` console.log(this.parentLinkToGoBackTo);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by creating a global variable, named `globalparentlink` here.

```
var app = angular.module('wizardApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){
  $scope.showpagetwo = function(title, id, parentlink){
    console.log("Title: " + title, id, parentlink);
    globalparentlink = parentlink;
    ...
  };

  $scope.goback = function(parentlink){
    console.log(globalparentlink);
    ...
  };

});
```